# Multithreading with Matlab

Tags: c, multithreading, matlab, mex

I'm working on a project on Matlab where we have to optimize the performance, and I was thinking about parallelizing a couple of function calls that were made from a .m file.

The idea was simple, from a Matlab file (.m) call a C file compiled as MEX, and from that C file, create a couple of threads and call back the matlab functions from each thread.

The theory works, I can create the threads, and I can also call the matlab function, the problem is that I cannot call the matlab function from the thread:

```
//Global variables
mxArray **g_plhs;
mxArray **g_prhs;
int g_nlhs;
int g_nrhs;

//Thread function
DWORD WINAPI my_function( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{
    mexCallMATLAB(g_nlhs,g_plhs,g_nrhs,g_prhs,"matlab_function");
    return 0; 
}


//Main function
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {

    DWORD dwThreadIdArray[MAX_THREADS];
    HANDLE  hThreadArray[MAX_THREADS]; 
    g_plhs = plhs;
    g_prhs = prhs;
    g_nlhs = nlhs;
    g_nrhs = nrhs;

    hThreadArray[0] = CreateThread( 
        NULL,                   
        0,                      
        my_function,            
        NULL,                   
        0,                      
        &dwThreadIdArray[0]);   

    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for(i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Do we have any restriction on that option when working with matlab? 
Has somebody tried something like this?

Edit: Is there any option that doesn't require Parallel Toolbox?

Comment: What MATLAB code are you trying to parallelize?

Comment: @rlbisbe: The MEX API is not thread-safe: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-V3B5T/index.html?solution=1-V3B5T

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only call the mx* and mex* functions from the MATLAB main thread. You can write multithreaded MEX files providing these do their work at a level below the mx interface. If you want multiple MATLAB interpreters, you need multiple MATLAB processes. One way is through the Parallel Computing Toolbox as pointed out by @You. This gives you `PARFOR` loops and `SPMD` blocks for running things simultaneously.

Comment: And without Parallel Computing Toolbox there would be any option?

Comment: @rlbisbe: here is an example of parallelized code using OpenMP (as long as you don't call MEX API functions from spawned threads): http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=1795 (also check out the comments for suggested alternatives to PCT)

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably be better off using MATLABs built-in multithreading features such as [`parfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/parfor.html). In fact, many MATLAB functions are already multithreaded (including matrix operations), so there should be no need for you to parallelize things yourself apart from replacing `for` with `parfor`. (In general, `while` loops cannot be paralellized.)

Comment: Parfor requires the Matlab parallel toolbox, and I don't have it on my Matlab license

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is `parfor`.  if you're a student you can get parallel toolbox for pretty cheap.  even full price is not much if you're serious about performance.  Your code above will be error prone and hard to test.  using `parfor` is intuitive and clean.

Comment: How is your answer different from You's answer posted 5 hours earlier? Please make your answers substantial. If all you're saying is that the parallel toolbox is cheap, it is best if written as a comment under You's answer.

Comment: lol, indeed, it's not much different than You's or Edric answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised everyone is pushing for `parfor`.  I would encourage you to at least think through whether you can design your algorithm to be called from Matlab and run the critical sections low level from multithreaded C/C++ without calling back to mex.  This should generally be possible.  Especially if you use Matlab `profiler` or similar tool to figure out which steps of your analysis are the bottleneck, then you may be able to write only 1 or 2 steps in multithreaded C.

Another way to go would be to write your parallelism in Java, which is easier to work with from Matlab.

Other options you might want to check out include the [`multicore` submission on Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13775-multicore-parallel-processing-on-multiple-cores) or the [`MatlabMPI` library](http://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/isr/matlabmpi/matlabmpi.html).  Both are a little kludgy and are designed for interprocess parallelism (you have to run multiple instances of Matlab), so not good for very fine-grained, complicated parallelism.  But for simply breaking a job into 4 or 8 or 16 parts they should get the job done, and at least `multicore` has reasonable community support.  I haven't tried `MatlabMPI` yet, but it looks promising.  As a bonus, these should work across multiple machines although they will probably require a shared network filesystem.