# How to call mexCallMATLAB from another thread

Tags: multithreading, matlab, unix, pthreads, mex

I'm creating a C++ module for MATLAB compiled by mex. I start a new thread in this module and call the matlab function myCallback from it:

```
mxArray *funcName = mxCreateString("myCallback");
mxArray *text - mxCreateString("AAA");
mxArray *call[2] = {funcName, text};
mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 2, call, "feval");
...
```

myCallback function:

```
function myCallback(text)
fprintf(1,'%s\n', text);
end
```

And it doesn't print anything after calling mexCallMATLAB. These functions work well in the same thread as matlab functions. What is a problem?

Comment: See my answer below. It answers the basic question of why you can't use `mex*` functions from multiple threads. But a bigger question is *why* you're trying to do it. Why? You'll want to think about redesigning the code in some way.

Comment: See also the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759088/multithreading-with-matlab).

Comment: I'm going to implement a matlab-client program that receives the answer from a server. So this process must be asynchronous and matlab client should not be wait an answer to continue its program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-V3B5T/index.html?solution=1-V3B5T).

Basically, the answer is that the `mex*` functions are *not* thread safe. This includes `mexCallMATLAB`, `mexPrintf`, and friends (yes, even mexPrintf shouldn't be called from multiple threads). All `mexCallMATLAB` calls must be done from the main thread (i.e., the same thread of execution as MATLAB itself).